# QtServiceFramework/QServicePluginInterface: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt5.2

I'm facing the below error while building my qt project. How to fix this problem, Do i need to install any plugins, if yes what are they and where to find them. Thanks in advance.

> fatal error: QtServiceFramework/QServicePluginInterface: No such file or directory
>
> compilation terminated.

Comment: When / where do you get the error, when try to include somethink? Some code could be useful.

Comment: while building my qt application

Comment: If I understand the error right you need the QtMobility API, see http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtmobility-1.2.0/installation.html

Comment: It is not getting downloaded from that site, i have tried.